# GStreamer v1.0 UDP Multicast streaming not properly decoded if client starts after server

Tags: udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, multicast

I am trying to make UDP Multicast screen streaming using GStreamer. My screen casting **server should run on Windows** and my **client should run on Linux**.

If I start the client before the server, everything is fine.

The problem is when I start the client and the server had already been launched. The video is received, but it is terribly distorted.

[This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mShWD.jpg)

Server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e gdiscreencapsrc ! queue ! video/x-raw, framerate=25/1 ! videoconvert ! \
       x264enc noise-reduction=10000 tune=zerolatency bitrate=2500  speed-preset="fast" byte-stream=true threads=4 key-int-max=15 intra-refresh=true ! \
             h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 \
       ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5000 auto-multicast=true
```

Client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc multicast-group=224.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=5000 ! application/x-rtp  ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink caps='video/x-raw, format=RGB'
```

I have already tried using `dx9screencapsrc`, but the behaviour is the same.
The issue is fixed only if I replace `gdiscreencapsrc` with `videotestsrc`.

If I launch the server on Linux, using `ximagesrc`, I still have some issues, but the video is improving over time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest reading on `rtpbin` element. It does a lot of stuff like rtp jitter buffer, packet reordering etc.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `cabac=false` to my x264enc element fixed the ussue.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v gdiscreencapsrc ! queue ! video/x-raw,framerate=60/1 ! decodebin ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! \
       x264enc cabac=false tune=zerolatency bitrate=4000  speed-preset="fast" ! \
             h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1 \
       ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5000 auto-multicast=true sync=false
```